# How to make `st_join` stricter?

Tags: r, spatial-join, sf

I used `st_join()` to combine `t1` and `t2`.

```
library(sf)
j <- st_join(
  x = t1,
  y = t2
)
```

`t1` represents voting precincts boundaries and `t2`, school zone boundaries. In some cases, the boundaries of `t1` fit perfectly in one school zone but because the borders touch two other zones, `st_join` lines up a precinct with three zones.

How can I make `st_join` stricter so that if a precinct in `t1` is mostly or seemingly entirely within a zone boundary of `t2`, the precinct lines up with only that zone, no others?

Comment: Hi! I think you may want to check `?sf::st_relate` and [DE-9IM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM). Moreover, can you share an example for `t1` and `t2`?

Comment: You could merge them with `st_intersection`, compute the respective area size with `st_area`, and then select the combinations above a certain area size. If e.g. less than one percent of a voting precinct's area intersects with a certain school zone, you drop that combination.